# Copy all files from a folder it's content into a document

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I want to copy all of the content of the `Documents` folders into a folder in the `Documents` folder. The script I wrote can copy the folders but it doesn't copy the files inside those folders. How can make it so it copies everything including files images or whatever is in the `Documents` folder.

```
$Files = Get-ChildItem  
New-Item -Name Storage -ItemType Directory 
Copy-Item $Files -Destination Storage
```

Comment: This worked for me: `$Files=gci $env:USERPROFILE\documents;$files|copy-item -dest $env:USERPROFILE\documents\storage -force`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how determined you are to keep your script pure PowerShell, but a simple solution would be to just use the `robocopy` tool with the `/E` flag to copy files and directories in subdirectories.

Syntax: `robocopy source_dir destination_dir /E`